# Can't connect to MySQL using user with password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am setting up my local development environment using XAMPP for writing websites using Laravel.
The issue im facing is that I cannot connect to the MySQL database with any new user I create. I give one user limited privileges for only one database and cannot connect using the correct password.

I tried making an admin user with full privileges on all databases and tables, and still cannot connect with the correct password.

The returned error is always the same -

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'laravel'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

and

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`
where laravel is the username, admin is the other one etc.

This is not related to Laravel as I keep getting this error even when I try to connect from the command line (as shown in error code number 2).

The 'anonymous' user has been removed to make sure MySQL doesn't match it by mistake, I have flushed privileges and restarted services countless times.
The default root user without password can connect, but no new users that I create with passwords can.

Comment: Did you set the new account up with `localhost` as the domain name?

Comment: Yes all accounts have localhost as domain

Comment: And are you connecting from localhost or some other pc?

Comment: Local environment connecting from same pc which is running apache and MySQL servics

Comment: How are you testing the new users? Do you try connecting from the CLI for example?

Comment: I try connecting from the CLI yes as shown in the errors in the original post

Comment: Try setting up another `'laravel'@'127.0.0.1'` as another test

Comment: And did you FLUSH after creating the new accounts?

Comment: No change,i am still getting the admin@localhost in the errors though, should it be that way even though I set it up as 127.0.0.1

Comment: Also yes I always flush privilege

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by re-installing XAMPP, nothing else.